# snowflake to SSIS connection using ssh auth c (external browser auth working fine)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Need help on connecting SSIS to snowflake using ssh key pair authentication method.

Create a DSN with the required values for:
User: Your Snowflake User
Server: Your Tenant URL
Database: YourDatabase
Schema: Your Schema
Warehouse: YourWarehouse
Role: YourRole
Authenticator:  ???

what to mention in the authenticator field when i use ssh key pair auth

any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

When using key/pair authentication with ODBC you need to set:

```
AUTHENTICATOR = SNOWFLAKE_JWT
```

Specifies to authenticate the Snowflake connection using key pair authentication with JSON Web Token (JWT).

For more information have a look [here](https://AUTHENTICATOR%20=%20SNOWFLAKE_JWT%20Specifies%20to%20authenticate%20the%20Snowflake%20connection%20using%20key%20pair%20authentication%20with%20JSON%20Web%20Token%20(JWT).).

Comment: it worked fine .. Thanks